# Unicast ARP Requests

Tags: protocols, wireshark, arp

I captured in kali linux arp package with wireshark, and saw a arp who-has package with ethernet layer Dest is unicast and not broadcast. And I can't figure it out.

Can someone explain how a arp who-has can be unicast?

```
eth.dst: 00:50:56:e3:28:0f
eth.src: 00:0c:11:11:11:11
eth.type: 0x0806

arp.opcode: 1
arp.src.hw_mac: 00:0c:11:11:11:11
arp.src.proto_ipv4: 192.168.52.132
arp.dst.hw_mac: 00:00:00:00:00:00
arp.dst.proto_ipv4: 192.168.52.2
```

You can download the pcap file from [here](https://mega.co.nz/#!K9pA0KKQ!LNmx4rGjZ52qQNLz3-BuX_Qv1TXMdkvLEFBxEUtVgN0), see packet no. 3

```
kali's ifconfig: 
ip: 192.168.52.132
mac: 00:0c:11:11:11:11
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer, it's part of the rfc 1122 -
2.3.2.1 (2) - Unicast Poll

http://www.embeddedsystemtesting.com/2012/08/can-arp-request-be-unicast.html